# Creating directed graph

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to R and igraph, I need to create a graph for this kind of data

```
  Origin    Dest    Flights valDist
1   JFK     LAX      168    2475
2   JFK     SJU      111    1597
3   JFK     SJU      111    NA
4   JFK     SFO      109    2586
```

Create a directed graph where Origin is first node. Length of edge depend on "valDist" longer this value is further away from First node it is. And it should be sorted by "Flights" highest to lowest.

This is what i have done so far

```
G <- graph.data.frame(DirectedGraph.Data, directed=TRUE, vertices=NULL)
#this is name of the node
V(G)$name <- with(DirectedGraph.Data, paste0(DirectedGraph.Data$Dest, " "
 ,DirectedGraph.Data$Flights, " " ,DirectedGraph.Data$valDist))
 #G <- set.graph.attribute(G, "layout", layout.drl(G))
#G <- set.graph.attribute(G, "length", )
plot(G, vertex.label= V(G)$name, vertex.size=150,layout=layout.graphopt)
```

When i plot this i am getting node on top of each other. I am just looking for guidence since i don't really know how do i define edge length depending on distance. secondly i don't know how do i show in a way where descending order depend on "Flights"

[image: Something like this]

Comment: What about `plot(G, vertex.label= V(G)$name, vertex.size=50, vertex.label.cex=.7, layout=layout.spring)` - adjusting the node sizes and their labels font sizes + experimenting with different graph layouts? Check `?layout` and `?plot.igraph` for the help files.

Comment: I am trying to do it using draw circle and draw lines. Hopefully this will work.